# Return CSV from Api without putting all database results in string

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

So what I want to do is have an api that gets a couple of columns from a big database, and returns them as CSV (text).
The problem arises if i try to first get them, then build the csv, because the memory fills up quickly
(400mb for 800k rows).
This is the closest I've gotten to getting it to work, but The format isn't really CSV, It's rows separated by Quotes, and it isn't a single string.

```
 public IEnumerable<string> getCSV()
    {

        var names = typeof(AddressBook).GetProperties()
                    .Select(property => property.Name)
                    .ToArray();
        yield return string.Join(",", names);
        foreach( string name  in names)

        var query = context.AddressBook.Select(x => string.Join(",", x.Name, x.Surname, x.BirthDate)).AsNoTracking();


        foreach (string row in query)
        {
            yield return row;
        }

    }
```

Comment: try using Skip() and Take() in a recursive function.

Comment: 800K rows isn't all that much, The problem is the code itself, it generates a lot of temporary strings. Every substring operation results in a *new* string. That's why it's a standard advice to use StringBuilder to construct large strings. Better yet, *instead* of returning individual strings and keeping them in memory, write them out to a temporary file immediatelly

Comment: An even better option would be to use a library like CsvHelper to write directly to a TextWriter the data that you read from `foreach` loop, without using `ToList()`. You don't need `Skipt()` and `Take()` when you read data row by row after all.

Comment: So I get the strings and write them to a temporary file, and then return the whole file (as a fileStream I assume)? 
the code above works ok, and doesn't have a big memory effect, but it isn't really csv. I guess my question is whether there exists an option to stream text data through an api endpoint

Answer (score 0):

1. Your program shouldn't occupy too much memory. It may through `MemoryOutOfBounds` exception.
2. API's are intended for quick response. Your api shouldn't take large time to execute/return the data.
3. If you have too much data, it is recommended to implement pagination for your api.

Comment: But i'm not trying to return a json object with pages of data, just a single big csv file.

Comment: You are holding the data in a list before returning from the API. That means you are storing large data in memory. 400mb is huge.

Comment: I know, that's part of my question. 
The naive approach i have now, is get all the rows, convert them to CSV (using String builder), and then return the big string.
but this isn't good. So i tried the method in the op, which kind of works, in that it doesn't use much memory, and it returns row by row, but it doesn't give me a real csv format. 
is there a way i can do both?